# Volume of solid revolution of region bounded by $y = x^{2} - 4, y = 8 - 2x^{2}, x=0, x=3$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, volume

I have two curves: $y_{1} = x^{2} - 4$, $y_{2} = 8 - 2x^{2}$. I have a region bounded by $y_{1}, y_{2}$, $y$-axis, and $x=3$. What is the volume of solid revolve around the $x$-axis?

---

**Attempt:**

In the image below, blue is $y_{2}$, red is $y_{1}$. And we see that the region consist of negative values of $y$, so how to calculate the volume using the disc method?

My analysis is that we cannot directly use the formula. For $0 \le x \le 2$, the volume is strictly 
$$ V_{1} = \pi \int_{0}^{2} (y_{2})^{2} dx$$ because $|y_{2}| \ge |y_{1}|$ in the region. Similarly, 
$$ v_{2} = \pi \int_{2}^{3} (y_{2})^{2} dx $$
so we have 
$$ V = \pi \int_{0}^{3} (8-2x^{2})^{2} dx = \pi \int_{0}^{3} 64 -32 x^{2} + 4x^{4} dx$$
$$ = \pi (64x - (32/3)x^{3} + (4/5)x^{5})|_{0}^{3} = 98.4 \pi $$

[image]

The 2nd image below is the plot of $|y_{2}|, |y_{1}|$:

[image]

Comment: how are you using the info about first curve $y=x^2-4$?

Comment: It is not used to calculate the volume @ganeshie8 . Let me add another image.

Comment: oh right, $y = 8-2x^2$ "covers" it. in your new graph did you take absolute value of the curves?

Comment: Yes, @ganeshie8 the volume resulting from revolution of $y_{1}$ is totally  inside the volume resulting from revoluiton of $y_{2}$.

Comment: yeah your work and graphs look pretty good to me:) that first curve must be given to trick haha